# Testing with a Virgin Mobile Chaser phone

Tags: android, testing, device

I just purchased a Virgin Mobile "Chaser" Android phone in order to test my apps with a real phone. I can't get Eclipse (running on my Windows 7 system) to see the phone.

I:

- put `android:debuggable="true"` into my manifest file.
- enabled USB debugging on the phone.
- installed the `Chaser_Driver_Setup_V1.2.1`.

The phone shows up on Device Manager as `android Composite ADB Interface`.

The driver details for that entry are:

- `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\winusb.sys`
- `C:\Windows\system32\WdfCoInstaller01007.dll`
- `C:\Windows\system32\WinUSBCoInstaller.dll`

Those last two drivers were installed (I suspect) when I did the Chaser driver install.

Eclipse cannot see the device.

When I run the command prompt `adb devices` from my `android-sdk\platform-tools directory` nothing is listed.

PS: If the administrators of this forum find this question inappropriate would they please tell me where it should be posted?  Thanks.

Gary

Comment: Try restarting the `adb` daemon. There's an option for it in the Devices view's toolbar in Eclipse, or run `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` from the command line. Then see if your device is recognized. If that does not help, reboot and see if your device is recognized.

Comment: Tried all that to no avail.  I see in the chaser forum at androidforums.com Another person had same problem.  Looks like it's a bum phone.