# List of phones that will work with Eclipse?

Tags: android, device

I need an android phone to test my apps with that will work with Eclipse.  It has to be low cost, run Gingerbread with modest memory and CPU.

Thinking that any android phone would work I recently purchased a Virgin Mobil Chaser but as it turns out, it cannot be seen by either Eclipse or adb (but device manager does see the phone).  Another developer has also had the same identical problem with the Chaser.

I could keep buying phones and see if they work but that could be long and frustrating.  I hope to find a "no contract" phone.

Is there any list of phones that work with Eclipse.  Does anyone know of any other Virgin Mobil phones that will work?
thanks, Gary

Comment: Did you try enabling USB debugging on the phone? http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: The Chaser is supposed to work. The beginning of http://redigua.com/how-to-root-virgin-mobile-chaser.html talks about connecting the phone via adb which is what you need for Eclipse.

Comment: the Chaser does NOT work for me nor for three other developers I know of.  I accept any answer that correctly answers my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One correct answer to my question is: the LG Optimus Elite works fine as a test phone.  Drivers installed immediately.  Also, it's less than $100 with no contract.

I still haven't found anyone who has gotten the PCD Chaser to work.
Gary

Answer (score 1):

**Any android phone should work**. And it is not Eclipse you need it to be compatible with. You need ADB drivers for the device so ADT tools can communicate with device. So what you need is to install ADB drivers for your phone and then, once installed, you should be able to see your device once you enable USB debugging on the device. Then ADB should be able to see it (either in Eclipse plugin or via command line `adb devices`).

**EDIT** if you are on Windows, then enabling USB Debugging on the device and connecting it to the computer should result in Windows asking for ADB drivers. You may try if "stock" (these available with SDK in `<SDK>\extras\google\usb_driver`) are suitable. If not, check manufacturer website (for HTC you may need to install HTC Sync) and if this fail, just google for your device name along with "ADB drivers" and you should get something usable shortly.

Comment: And if you can't find ADB drivers for it, there are articles on the web, esp at XDA Devs, that describe how to hack the standard Google ones.

Comment: Yes, that may also be the option to hack `.ini` file provided to add entry matching vendor/product IDs

Comment: Don't know if you have seen my other post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435215/testing-with-a-virgin-mobil-chaser-phone but I have tried all sorts of drivers and the "Chaser Drivers" are the only ones that will install and allow Windows 7 to see my phone.  Could spend weeks trying to hack drivers but would rather develop software.  Virgin mobil Advanced tech support never heard of ADB.  I just need a phone that works.

Comment: Virgin is just a carrier. You may do not bother much (unless they sell units with modified firmware and disabled ADB bridge). What device you got?

Comment: WebnetMobile: you ask "What device you got?"  In my post I said that it is a Virgin Mobile (pcd) Chaser.  PCD can't be contacted as they are just a distribution label and Virgin Mobile knows nothing about their phones.  I didn't really understand the rest of your comment.